# concrete mathematics: josephus problem

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

I am going through `Concrete Mathematics` and am having some difficulty understanding this particular spot in the chapter which introduces the Josephus problem.  Hopefully someone can clarify.

```
So let's suppose that we have 2n people originally. After the 1rst go around,
we're left with

 **image showing just the odd members left.**

and 3 will be the next to go. This is just like starting out with n people, except
that each person's number has been doubled and decreased by 1. That is,
       J(2n) = 2J(n) - 1 ; for n >= 1.
We can now go quickly to large n. For example, we know that J(10) = 5, so
        J(20) = 2J(10) - 1 = 2·5 - 1 = 9 :
```

Here is what I do not understand:

```
Similarly J(40) = 17, and we can deduce that J(5·2^m) = 2^(m+1) + 1.
```

How did we deduce `J(5·2^m) = 2^(m+1) + 1.`?  It seems to pop out of nowhere to me.

Comment: Look at $J(10) = 5 = 4 + 1$, $J(20) = 9 = 8 + 1$, $J(40) = 17 = 16 + 1$ — how would you generalize this sequence? And how would you prove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unraveling the recursion gives you a guess for the final form, which you can then prove by induction as Ross does in his answer:  $$\begin{align*} J(5 \cdot 2^m) &= 2 J(5 \cdot 2^{m-1}) - 1 \\ &= 4 J(5 \cdot 2^{m-2}) - 3 \\ &= 8 J(5 \cdot 2^{m-3}) - 7 \\ &= \ldots \\ &= 2^m J(5 \cdot 2^0) - (2^m - 1) \\ &= 2^m (J(5) - 1) + 1 = 2^m (3-1) + 1 \\ &= 2^{m+1} + 1. \end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I did a little more research and I found this page a lot easier to understand. My dexterity in math is pretty much zero.  So I need to read what is going on :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem

Answer (score 0):

Having derived $J(20)=9$, he plugs in $n=20$ in the relation $J(2n)=2J(n)-1$ to get $J(40)=2\cdot 9 -1=17$

The next comes by induction. We have the base case

$$
J(10)=J(5\cdot 2)=5
$$

which satisfies

$$
J(5\cdot 2^m)=2^{m+1}+1  \hspace{1cm}\text{with:} \hspace{2mm}m=1
$$

Then:

$$
J(5 \cdot 2^{m+1})=2(2^{m+1}+1)-1=2^{m+2}+1
$$

Comment: Ah, ok I see.  Thanks for laying that out for me.